# Complie issue with Custom GWT project strcuture

Tags: gwt, maven

I am working on a gwt module that is built using maven build system. I
had a working module that had the following project structure.

> project-name/src/main/java/pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/EntryPoingClass 
>   project-name/src/man/resources/pkg1/pkg2/ModuleDef.gwt.xml

The module definition was looking like this (I have put only this
project specific settings here...normal inherits are not specified for
the sake of brevity)

> ... 
>  <entry-point class='pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.EntryPointClass'/>
>   <source path='pkg3'/>
> ...

I am not a big fan of having sub packages in the resources folder.
Hence I am trying to change it to something like the following

> project-name/src/main/java/pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/EntryPoingClass 
>  project-name/src/man/resources/ModuleDef.gwt.xml

Also changed the module definition to

> ... 
>  <entry-point class='pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.EntryPointClass'/>
>   <source path='pkg1.pkg2.pkg3'/> <!-- Since the module def is not
>   inside any package I am specifying the entire 'client' package here --> 
> ...

After this, invoking gwt compile fails with the following error

Unable to find type "pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.EntryPointClass"

Can anybody tell me if there is any relation between the package
structure of the EntryPointClass and the module definition package
structure apart from the fact that the EntryPointClass should be
inside the 'client' package specified in the module definition (which
is satisfied here)?

Btw, I could see that the compiled classes are available in the
classpath when invoking the gwt compiler.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GWT compiler needs sources of client side classes, not only compiled bytecode. Is it in classpath?

In my company we always set pom.xml to copy sources to target as resources:

```
<build>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/client/**/*.java</include>
      <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
</build>
```

Change `**/client/**/*.java` to anything satisfies your needs (probably `pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/**/*.java`). This way sources of client part are always in classpath.